# How to Create a Fiscal Year Instead of Current Year?

Tags: 2010

I’m using SharePoint Designer 2010 for a list workflow.  I also have a second workflow and list that auto generates an “ID Number” in a column (using variables) with the current year and the next sequential number (FY2014-0002), which is added to each new record.  A column titled “Prefix” contains the “FY.”

How do I change the current year to display a fiscal year, which starts Oct 1, and looks like FY15-0001 or FY2015-0001. I know how to change the year manually but I want it to auto-update on Oct 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to auto enter a fiscal year in my list starting Oct 1 that returns only the year value (FY2015).

1. Created a calculated column (single line of text) with the following IF statement:
   =IF(MONTH(Created)>9,"FY"&YEAR(Created)+1,"FY"&YEAR(Created))
2. I then used variables and LookUp to place the fiscal year and the next sequential number in another column looking like this:  FY2015-0001.  The sequential number was created by a second workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use a formula to calculate the Fiscal Year.

Something like:

```
if (currentMonth > 10)
    currentFY= currentYear +1
else 
    currentFY = currentYear
```

Comment: Thank you. Where do I use this statement? Right now I have a string of variables that display these in the ID field. Variable: PrefixValue, Variable: This Year,-Variable: SuffixValue

Comment: use condition plus Do Calculation action

Comment: I just learned the fiscal year date will be based on the forms submission date (Created field).  So I need to display the the fiscal year in my ID Number column based of the Created date.  I'm still confused as to whether I use this IF staement imbedded into a Condition or Action item or if I create it using those same Condition and Action items. For example: where do I find (currentMonth), in a Condition or Action....I assume I don't?

Comment: Are you using InfoPath form? if yes, then you can include those codes in the code behind.